# pan.sh not returning a return code inside eval

Tags: bash, pentaho, kettle

I've got a shell script which is calling Pentaho's `pan.sh` to execute a job. The job itself is failing, but I can't seem to capture the return code to fail the shell script wrapper.

This is the code I'm using to execute the batch:

```
echo "Processing $FILE file...";
cmd="./pan.sh -file=$FILE -param:db.name=${DB_NAME} -param:db.host=${DB_HOST} -param:db.port=${DB_PORT} -param:db.user=${DB_USER} db.password=${DB_PASSWORD} -param:dataload.dir=${DATALOAD_DIR}"
eval $cmd
ret_code = $?
echo $ret_code
if [ $ret_code -ne 0 ]
  then
    echo "return code = ${ret_code}"
else
  echo "return code is ok ${ret_code}"
fi;
```

Then the relevant part of the log that's output looks like this. You can see that it's not outputting anything in `ret_code` variable. I can't spot what the issue is. It might be bash, or might be `pan.sh`. I'm not sure.

```
utils.dataload.DataLoadProcessWrapper 76 run - 2015/09/16 20:04:51 - Language Lookup.0 - Finished processing (I=2, O=0, R=3, W=3, U=0, E=0)
20:04:51.448 DEBUG com.ocscommerce.services.utils.dataload.DataLoadProcessWrapper 76 run - 2015/09/16 20:04:51 - Existing Id Lookup.0 - Finished processing (I=4, O=0, R=3, W=3, U=0, E=0)
20:04:51.450 DEBUG com.ocscommerce.services.utils.dataload.DataLoadProcessWrapper 76 run - 2015/09/16 20:04:51 - Add constants.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=3, W=3, U=0, E=0)
20:04:51.453 DEBUG com.ocscommerce.services.utils.dataload.DataLoadProcessWrapper 76 run - 2015/09/16 20:04:51 - Filter rows.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=3, W=3, U=0, E=0)
20:04:51.469 DEBUG com.ocscommerce.services.utils.dataload.DataLoadProcessWrapper 76 run - 2015/09/16 20:04:51 - Allocate New Key.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=2, W=0, U=0, E=2)
20:04:51.470 DEBUG com.ocscommerce.services.utils.dataload.DataLoadProcessWrapper 76 run - 2015/09/16 20:04:51 - Abort.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=1, U=0, E=1)
20:04:51.470 DEBUG com.ocscommerce.services.utils.dataload.DataLoadProcessWrapper 76 run - 2015/09/16 20:04:51 - customers - Transformation detected one or more steps with errors.
20:04:51.471 DEBUG com.ocscommerce.services.utils.dataload.DataLoadProcessWrapper 76 run - 2015/09/16 20:04:51 - customers - Transformation is killing the other steps!
20:04:51.471 DEBUG com.ocscommerce.services.utils.dataload.DataLoadProcessWrapper 76 run - 2015/09/16 20:04:51 - Replace CSV Nulls.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=1, U=0, E=0)
20:04:51.472 DEBUG com.ocscommerce.services.utils.dataload.DataLoadProcessWrapper 76 run - 2015/09/16 20:04:51 - Sort by Email.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=0, U=0, E=0)
20:04:51.830 DEBUG com.ocscommerce.services.utils.dataload.DataLoadProcessWrapper 76 run - 2015/09/16 20:04:51 - Pan - Finished!
20:04:51.831 DEBUG com.ocscommerce.services.utils.dataload.DataLoadProcessWrapper 76 run - 2015/09/16 20:04:51 - Pan - Start=2015/09/16 20:04:35.089, Stop=2015/09/16 20:04:51.830
20:04:51.832 DEBUG com.ocscommerce.services.utils.dataload.DataLoadProcessWrapper 76 run - 2015/09/16 20:04:51 - Pan - Processing ended after 16 seconds.
20:04:51.848 DEBUG com.ocscommerce.services.utils.dataload.DataLoadProcessWrapper 76 run - 
20:04:51.849 DEBUG com.ocscommerce.services.utils.dataload.DataLoadProcessWrapper 76 run - return code is ok
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can't put whitespace around the equal sign in an assignment statement. (Doing so makes it a regular command call, not an assignment.)

```
ret_code=$?
```

Second, don't use `eval` here. Either define a function:

```
cmd () {
    ./pan.sh -file="$FILE" \
             -param:db.name="${DB_NAME}" \
             -param:db.host="${DB_HOST}" \
             -param:db.port="${DB_PORT}" \
             -param:db.user="${DB_USER}" \
             -param:db.password="${DB_PASSWORD}" \
             -param:dataload.dir="${DATALOAD_DIR}"
}
```

or separate the command from the arguments:

```
cmd=./pan.sh
arguments=(-file="$FILE"
           -param:db.name="${DB_NAME}"
           -param:db.host="${DB_HOST}"
           -param:db.port="${DB_PORT}"
           -param:db.user="${DB_USER}"
           -param:db.password="${DB_PASSWORD}"
           -param:dataload.dir="${DATALOAD_DIR}"
)
"$cmd" "${arguments[@]}"
```

Comment: ah bash, it's so finicky with spaces! Thanks, ok I'll try to take out the eval too. cheers, I'm sure this will work now.